# Worklight - Send greek characters over HTTP

Tags: character-encoding, httprequest, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

In Worklight I am trying to sent an HTTP request (via HTTP adapter) that includes parameters with Greek letters. However the encoding applied, alters the Greek letters to hieroglyphics. Does anyone know how I can make the request send Greek characters?

```
var request = 
    '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'
   + '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" '
   + 'xmlns:test="">'
   +    '<soapenv:Header/>'
   +        '<soapenv:Body>'
   +            '<test:getAnalysis>'
   +                '<request>'
   +                    '<invoiceId>' + invoiceId + '</invoiceId>'
   +                '</request>'
   +            '</test:getAnalysis>'
   +        '</soapenv:Body>'
   + '</soapenv:Envelope>';

  var options = {
        method : 'post',
        returnedContentType : 'xml',
        path : getPath(),
        body: {
            content: request.toString(),
            contentType: 'text/xml; charset=utf-8',
        },
    };
return WL.Server.invokeHttp(options).Envelope.Body;
```

Comment: What encoding are you using? How are you applying it?

Comment: Can you include a sample of your code?

Comment: I've just tried making an HTTP adapter send greek data to a test server and it worked fine. You can try as well. Send a POST with a parameter named `data` to this URL: http://burnished-yeti-689.appspot.com/

Comment: @asterix, any updates to this question?

Comment: Thanks @Asterix. Would you mind writing this as an answer rather than a comment?

Answer (score 0):

The above request works fine. UTF-8 was the only thing needed. The issue with the encoding appeared when I tried calling the adapter via eclipse. When the adapter was called via the application, the parameters were sent using the correct encoding.